# Roots of of the derivative of a polynomial are in the convex hull of the polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis

$(def)$: The $\mathbf{Convex}$ $\mathbf{Hull}$ of a set $\{ z_1,\ldots,z_k \} \subset \mathbb{C}$ is the set

$$ CH[z_1,\ldots,z_k] = \left\{ z \in \mathbb{C} : z = \sum_{j=1}^k \lambda_j z_j, \; \; 0 \leq \lambda_j \leq 1 \; \; such \;\; that\;\; \sum_{j=1}^k \lambda_j = 1 \right\}$$

$(Problem)$If $P$ is a complex polynomial, show that the roots of $P'$ belong to the convex hull of the roots of $P$

### Attempt:

Suppose the roots of $P$ are $r_1,\ldots,r_m $. We can write $P(z) = \prod_{j=1}^m (z -r_j) $. By applying logarithms in both sides, we obtain $\log P(z) = \sum \log( z - r_j) $. Differentiation gives:

$$ \frac{ P'(z)}{P(z) } = \sum_{j=1}^m\frac{1}{z-r_j} $$

Suppose $z$ is an arbitrary root of $P'(z)$. If $z$ is a root of $P(z)$, then the above equation does not make sense, so we impose that $P(z) \neq 0 $. We must show that $z \in CH[r_1,\ldots,r_m] $. Notice since $P'(z) = 0$, we have

$$ 0 = \sum_{j=1}^m\frac{1}{z-r_j} $$

Using the fact that $|z|^2 =z \overline{z} $ , we write the above expression as follows;

$$ 0 = \sum \frac{ \overline{z} - \overline{r_j} }{|z-r_j|^2} $$

and so

$$ \overline{z} \sum \frac{ 1}{|z-r_j|^2} = \sum \frac{ \overline{r_j}}{|z-r_j|^2 } $$

Here is where I am stuck since I dont know that how to express $z$ as linear combination of the $r_j's$. Any help would be grateful.

Comment: In your last equation conjugate, and divide throughout by $\sum|z-r_j|^{-2}$.

Comment: If you want italics, please oh please do not do monstruosities like `$(def)$` of `$\mathbf{something}$` but simply `*(def)*` or `**something**`. Read http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Comment: Sorry Mariano. I will keep that in mind next time. By the way, by your hint, I got

$$ z = \frac{ \sum \frac{ r_j}{|z-r_j|^2 }}{ \sum \frac{1}{|z-r_j|^2 } }$$

Comment: Is this correct?

Comment: Sure. That gives you $z$ as a linear combination of the $r_j$, and to finish you need to check that the coefficients satisfy the conditions required for $z$ to be in CH.

Comment: Got it! gracias Mariano! Un saludo desde Guayaquil...

Comment: You should now write a complete answer :-) (Thanks!)